# Missing Argument in Codeigniter making me insane

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys quick question according to my knowledge there is nothing wrong with the following statement as the code executes without error but it is not updating the information in the database here is my model and controller code

Controller:

```
    public function update_canvas($id){
    $this->check_is_validated();
    $data['success'] = 0;
    if ($_POST) {
        $data = array(
            'canvas_name' => $this->input->post('canvas_name')
        );
        $this->Art_m->edit_canvas($id,$data);
        $data['success'] = 1;
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/art');
    }else {
        $data['arty'] = $this->Art_m->get_canvas($id);
        $data['title'] = 'Edit your Art Works';
        $data['content'] = 'admin/art/edit_canvas';
        $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/template', $data);
    }
}
```

Model Code:

```
    function edit_canvas($id,$data)
{
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $this->db->update('art', $data);
}
```

So when I run the script and try update the info my error log gives the following and I can't see what the problem is here as it needs the ID to update correct?

Log Error:

```
ERROR - 2016-02-29 16:25:48 --> Severity: Warning --> Missing argument 1 for Art::update_canvas() C:\wamp\www\alisonbull\application\modules\art\controllers\Art.php 80
ERROR - 2016-02-29 16:25:48 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined variable: id C:\wamp\www\alisonbull\application\modules\art\controllers\Art.php 87
```

Please advise

Comment: have you send id from your form ??

Comment: Undefined variable: id ? that means no id in controller

Comment: Are you passing the ID through in the URL, such as `art/update_canvas/123`?  It looks like it might be being sent via $_POST on the form, and therefore not being passed through in the CodeIgniter routing.

Comment: The ID is missing either because it isn't present in the URI, or because one of your routes is modifying the call. Either way, your controller methods shouldn't assume that a parameter exists.

Comment: Thanks guys, @gabe3886 as soon as I read the part about the $_POST on the form I checked code in the view and saw my problem was there. Thanks for the assist it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing up my comment as an answer now that it's been confirmed as correct:

The issue is that the function is being called without a value specified in `$id` because the value meant for $id is being sent via $_POST.

In CodeIgniter application/config/routes.php, there will be a line like:

`$route['art/update/(:any)'] = 'art/update_canvas/$1';`

This tells CodeIgniter that when a request comes in on `art/update/42`, for example, it should call the art controller, the function `update_canvas` in that controller, and pass the 42 as the parameter to the controller.

As you're submitting the id within the $_POST request, this isn't being routed correctly so the $id isn't being set.  This is then causing the update to fail because it can't update with an empty ID

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error messages it could be you didn't pass in an `$id`?
CodeIgniter controller work like this:

Say you have this URL:

```
example.com/index.php/stack/your/url/42
```

The two segments (`url`, `42`) after `your` will be passed to the function as parameters:

```
class Stack extends CI_Controller {
    public function your($url, $id) {
        echo $url;
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @Amous